# Copy from email to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not an expert in VBA, got an error which I can't figure out, can you please help advise?

I need an excel macro to copy from all the emails in a folder to my excel, googled and found the below code. The code runs fine for some emails, after that there will be a runtime error 440: array index out of bounds at this line.

**abody = Split(objfolder.Items(i).Body, vbNewLine)**

Most of the time I just record macro and edit from there so I don't really understand what is array index out of bounds.
Really hope you can enlighten me, thank you so much in advance for your help... =)
Full code can be found below...

---

Added in the part where the macro will get the details of the email it's processing... But what is baffling me is the received details of the email does not match the body. Can anyone please help advise?

---

```
Sub test()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim olFldr As Object
Dim olMail As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim abody() As String
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim arrData() As Variant

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("temp")

Cnt = 0
For Each olMail In olFldr.Items
On Error GoTo errorhandler
Cnt = Cnt + 1

abody = Split(olFldr.Items(Cnt).Body, vbNewLine)

For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
Sheet1.Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = abody(j)
Next

ReDim Preserve arrData(1 To 1, 1 To Cnt)
arrData(1, Cnt) = olMail.ReceivedTime
Cells(1, 1).Value = arrData(1, Cnt)

Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"

olFldr.Items(Cnt).Move olNS.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Processed")

Next

Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olFldr = Nothing

errorhandler:
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olFldr = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

---

updated code:

```
Sub test()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim olFldr As Object
Dim olMail As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim abody() As String
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim arrData() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("temp")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

EmailCount = olFldr.Items.Count

MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

Cnt = 1
For Each olMail In olFldr.Items

abody = Split(olMail.Body, vbNewLine)

For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
ws.Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = abody(j)
Next

ReDim Preserve arrData(1 To 1, 1 To Cnt)
arrData(1, Cnt) = olMail.ReceivedTime
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = arrData(1, Cnt)

ws.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"

olMail.Move olNS.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Processed")

Cnt = Cnt + 1


Next

Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olFldr = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: the only problem i can think of is if you encounter a mail without body hence returning an `Empty` array. Can you try to add a break point and check if there's an instance that `abody` is empty?

Comment: Maybe not everything in the `temp` folder is a mail item?  Might be worth checking the type of the item before trying to access the `body`

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your advise... I've tried to add a breakpoint, I still can't figure out the pattern. As this macro will move the email from folder temp to processed, the weird part is if I end the error and rerun the macro, it will continue to move the emails until the last one. I also noticed that abody in the following is subscript out of range every time before the email is moved, but it works randomly. Anyone can help advise? [Sheet1.Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = abody(j)]

Comment: What happens if you change the line `For i = 1 To emailcount` to `For i = emailcount to 1 Step -1`

Comment: Hi Siddharth, thanks for your advise... Tried and it skipped from **For i = emailcount to 1** to **Set ObjOutlook = Nothing** =( none of the email is processed... Actually it is working if I run the macro a few times ie end the error and rerun the macro until all emails are moved out of the folder... I just find it so irritating that I can't figure out why error!!! =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to change your looping part to this.
Also add the declaration and variable assignment for the target Worksheet.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'added this to avoid the subscript out of range

Cnt = 1
For Each olMail In olFldr.Items
On Error GoTo errorhandler

    abody = Split(olMail.Body, vbNewLine) 'changed this to olMail.Body since you are already iterating each mail
    For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
    ws.Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = abody(j) 'use the declared ws here
    Next

    ReDim Preserve arrData(1 To 1, 1 To Cnt)
    arrData(1, Cnt) = olMail.ReceivedTime
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = arrData(1, Cnt) 'use ws here as well if same Sheet1
    ws.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    olMail.Move olNS.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Processed") 'change to olMail as well
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
Next
```

This is **untested** so i leave the testing to you. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your advise... I've tested out and it works fine however, the macro will not process all the emails available in the folder. I put a check on the count of emails in the macro but the macro will just end without processing all, with no error. That's so odd, do you have any idea? Anyway, I've included the updated code on the top for your reference... =)

Comment: np, glad it worked. so what problems have we solved so far? no subscript? and no error on `abody` now? the only problem is its not getting all the emails? is that correct? how do you know its not getting all? Why don't you put a `Msgbox Cnt & oMail.Subject` inside your loop so you can see what mails are processed and what's not. Then we will help you analyze. Right now, i can't see any reason for your the `loop` to fail.

Comment: Hihi, thanks again... Tried that, there's no error at all, I'm also very baffled. Email count is showing 5, but the macro runs until cnt = 3 only then stop. For now, I just had to re-run the macro again, until all the emails are moved to the processed folder. But just out of curiosity, any idea why is it behaving like that? Btw, is cnt the email count? If so, why is it necessary to put cnt = 1 when we are already looping `For Each olMail In olFldr.Items`? And also, what does `ReDim Preserve arrData(1 To 1, 1 To Cnt)` means? Sorry for the many questions, just very curious... =P

Comment: I was curious on that part as well. I preserve that part because i thought that's what you want to do :). `Redim Preserve arrData(1 to 1, 1 to Cnt)` only stores the mail received date data in the array. And yes,  we basically don't need the `Cnt`. I preserve it because i thought you will be needing the `arrData` somewhere else. If not, you can remove that part and directly pass the `olMail.ReceiveTime` on your target range.

Comment: hi there, thanks again... =) I've remove Cnt and also the array, and the macro works fine... Only issue is I need to re-run a few times until all the mails are moved, somehow the macro won't process all the emails in the folder, weird.. But anyways, it's good enough for me, thank you so much!! =D